# members and staff login info schema

Tags: sqlite

So I have two tables, members and staff. I need to create a login system which means I need to store usernames and passwords for both members and staff. How should it be implemented?

Comment: Maybe you would want to check this question [Database design : multiple category of users login into same system](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10115/9031) and the answer, it has some interesting information you could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create only a single table with the name user_login or whatever suits you best in that table make three columns with username, password and login_type/account_type, in the third columns store the type either it is member or staff.

Table: user_login
Fields: username, password, account_type

sample data:

user1 | user123 | member